# How to connect to facebook, and debug facebook application using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm really struggling trying to find something that actually works for getting the basics up and running. Even the tutorial apps that came with the SDK seems to have to be uploaded in order to work, so there's no easy way to debug and test it locally.

Anyone got a link to a working sample I could work off of?

Cheers!

---

This is what I currently have in my aspx. There's nothing in the code-behind:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FacebookTest.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Facebook" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    </p>
    <% var app = new FacebookApp();
       if (app.Session == null)
       {%>
        <img id="fbLogin" src="login-button.png" />
            <%
       }%>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ appId: '<%:FacebookSettings.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        $('#fbLogin').click(function () {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    //window.location = '<%--:Url.Action("Profile") --%>'
                } else {
                    // user cancelled login
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue with running the SDK locally? There shouldn't be any issue if the Facebook settings are set correctly.

Comment: Nathan, If I'm not mistaken, I shouldn't even bother with the javascript for a fully facebook-enabled page, right? I've got another question in another thread, and now I got fb and my computer at least mumbling to each other. Hopefully, I can make them a little less shy and at least authenticate tomorrow so I can start look at the rest of the SDK. I like a challenge, but... :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also fighting with this sdk. For local testing you must do the following

1. In Facebook application settings go to Website tab and change site URL to "http://localhost/"
2. You also need to set your asp.net development server port to 80 (write click your project and click properties, go to Web tab User Visual Studio Development server specific port). We are doing this because we set our site url to localhost, Facebook dont allow port number in site url.

Comment: Thanks, but at the moment I cannot even get the darned login-button clickable. It's kind of bugging me, as this should be the least code possible to get this running :S

Comment: Actually, FB *does* allow ports. I use mine at port 1500 :)