# Cannot Create Facebook App using Localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Did something change with Facebook recently? I can't seem to debug an app locally with an app setup as localhost. Here is what I did:

1. Setup a brand new application called "My test web application" and checked the box for "Terms and Conditions"
2. Choose "Edit Settings" -> "Web Site" and changed the Site URL to "http://localhost:{my port}/"

This doesn't seem to be working. I get the following before login:

[image]

Followed by the following after login:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (3/30/2011)**

So, based on a comment below, I've removed the port number from my URL. Now when I try to login, I get a bunch of JavaScript errors on the Facebook Login page that look like the following:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you use the correct Application ID?

Comment: Yes. Copied right from the site. I'm going to hand type it in again just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely correct. Is there another setting that I need to change? It shouldn't matter, but I'm using the Facebook C# SDK from CodePlex. It is on the Facebook login that I'm getting that. It does show the correct Facebook app name in that window too so I know it is pulling at least the appId correct and I did double check the appSecret too.

Comment: Strange, maybe you can try to add localhost to "site domain" as well. Haven't tried to use localhost myself, but I am using a virtual host, testsite.local witch point to localhost, and that works

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118994/how-to-connect-to-facebook-and-debug-facebook-application-using-c-sdk maybe it has something to do with the port number

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated the question above with the new issue.

Comment: maybe one step in the right direction then :), if you try opening the page in an other browser, does it work then? i.e in firefox or chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the Facebook Javascript SDK that prevents it from working on non-standard ports in IE. https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/#issue/106

Try it with the port in either Chrome or FF. The other option is to host it in IIS and set a host header. You can use the domain *.local.facebooksdk.com to point to your local host set * to whatever you want your subdomain to be. Or you can use any url and edit your host file.

Regarding your edit with the port removed, that is another bug in facebook's javascript sdk. There is something weird that happens where the domain is localhost with no port. Basically, the Javascript sdk expects a root domain unless there is a port.

So as you can see, the Javascript SDK is kind of a mess in these situations. The best thing is to run in IIS and edit your host header to run as a fake domain.

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error message if your redirect_uri (when logging user in) does not match (or is not a page within) one of the site urls that you specified for your app.  Since you specified http://localhost:{my port}/ for your site url, your return uri will need to be http://localhost:{my port}/ or a folder/page within that domain.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The URL locally is http://localhost:{my port}/. It's also specified in Facebook that way for the Site URL. Where else does it need to be changed? I don't see any type of Return URI parameter in the app setting.